# Logistic Regression algorithm did not converge

Tags: r, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I want to carry out logistic regression on a binary outcome variable (0 and 1). Summary of data looks like this:

```
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1044 obs. of  16 variables:
     $ age        : int  18 17 15 15 16 16 16 17 15 15 ...
     $ Medu       : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 2 2 5 4 5 3 5 4 4 ...
     $ Fedu       : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 2 2 3 4 4 3 5 3 5 ...
     $ got_parent : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ traveltime : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
     $ studytime  : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ failures   : int  0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ famrel     : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 5 4 3 4 5 4 4 4 5 ...
     $ freetime   : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 3 3 2 3 4 4 1 2 5 ...
     $ goout      : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 3 2 2 2 2 4 4 2 1 ...
     $ Dalc       : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Walc       : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ health     : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 3 3 5 5 5 3 1 1 5 ...
     $ absences   : int  6 4 10 2 4 10 0 6 0 0 ...
     $ final_grade: int  6 6 10 15 10 15 11 6 19 15 ...
     $ binge_drink: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Where binge_drink is the Y variable I want to predict. I split the data into train and test set with 70% split ratio, but when I run the code as follows I get the warning message:

```
    m1 <- glm(binge_drink ~., data = data_train, family = "binomial")

    Warning messages:
    1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
    2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

And the summary output looks like this:

```
    > summary(m1)

    Call:
    glm(formula = binge_drink ~ ., family = "binomial", data = data_train)

    Deviance Residuals: 
           Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
    -6.443e-06  -2.908e-06  -2.315e-06   2.110e-08   1.441e-05  

    Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    (Intercept) -2.975e+01  5.800e+05   0.000    1.000
    age          2.793e-02  1.018e+04   0.000    1.000
    Medu1        2.662e+00  5.230e+05   0.000    1.000
    Medu2        2.049e+00  5.229e+05   0.000    1.000
    Medu3        2.335e+00  5.235e+05   0.000    1.000
    Medu4        2.500e+00  5.233e+05   0.000    1.000
    Fedu1        2.100e-01  1.442e+05   0.000    1.000
    Fedu2        4.332e-01  1.457e+05   0.000    1.000
    Fedu3        4.615e-01  1.469e+05   0.000    1.000
    Fedu4        3.043e-01  1.477e+05   0.000    1.000
    got_parent1 -4.496e-01  4.591e+04   0.000    1.000
    traveltime2  1.706e-01  2.492e+04   0.000    1.000
    traveltime3  5.142e-01  4.216e+04   0.000    1.000
    traveltime4  3.188e-01  7.544e+04   0.000    1.000
    studytime2  -3.050e-02  2.572e+04   0.000    1.000
    studytime3   2.261e-02  3.546e+04   0.000    1.000
    studytime4  -4.446e-01  6.649e+04   0.000    1.000
    failures    -1.537e-03  1.925e+04   0.000    1.000
    famrel2      5.388e-01  8.514e+04   0.000    1.000
    famrel3      3.928e-01  6.791e+04   0.000    1.000
    famrel4      1.007e-01  6.622e+04   0.000    1.000
    famrel5      1.544e-01  6.772e+04   0.000    1.000
    freetime2    3.437e-01  5.248e+04   0.000    1.000
    freetime3    3.095e-01  4.963e+04   0.000    1.000
    freetime4   -7.933e-02  5.250e+04   0.000    1.000
    freetime5   -3.947e-01  6.455e+04   0.000    1.000
    goout2      -7.329e-02  4.856e+04   0.000    1.000
    goout3      -1.290e-01  4.948e+04   0.000    1.000
    goout4       8.735e-02  5.056e+04   0.000    1.000
    goout5       3.687e-01  5.613e+04   0.000    1.000
    Dalc2        5.186e+01  3.300e+04   0.002    0.999
    Dalc3        5.050e+01  5.089e+04   0.001    0.999
    Dalc4        5.030e+01  8.331e+04   0.001    1.000
    Dalc5        4.882e+01  8.648e+04   0.001    1.000
    Walc2        2.194e-01  3.208e+04   0.000    1.000
    Walc3        6.827e-01  3.267e+04   0.000    1.000
    Walc4        5.085e+01  3.812e+04   0.001    0.999
    Walc5        4.912e+01  6.719e+04   0.001    0.999
    health2      2.159e-01  4.387e+04   0.000    1.000
    health3      6.133e-02  4.077e+04   0.000    1.000
    health4     -2.094e-01  4.418e+04   0.000    1.000
    health5      2.766e-01  3.684e+04   0.000    1.000
    absences    -4.326e-03  1.951e+03   0.000    1.000
    final_grade  1.050e-02  3.322e+03   0.000    1.000

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

        Null deviance: 9.4833e+02  on 729  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 7.4180e-09  on 686  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 88

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

I have tried creating dummy variables for categorical predictors but the output is similar. Does anyone know why?

Thank you.

Comment: It's likely that one or more of the independent variables perfectly separates the outcomes into their correct classes. In this situation, there isn't a unique solution for the regression coefficients. For more details and what to do about it, see, for example, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254124/why-does-logistic-regression-become-unstable-when-classes-are-well-separated) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression).

Comment: Thank you @eipi10 ,

I have since resolved it. Realized that binge_drink is a derived variable from Dalc and Walc variables which have separated the outcomes perfectly as you mentioned. I have removed those from the dataset before running regression, and it works perfectly. Thank you :)